# getting this TypeError: is_valid() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, django

i am getting the typeError:
is_valid() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

please make me correct where i have done the mistake

```
def register(request):
registered = False

if request.method == "POST":
    user_form = UserForm(request.POST)
    profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if user_form.is_valid() and UserProfileInfoForm.is_valid():
        user = user_form.save()
        user.set_password(user.password)
        user.save()

        profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
        profile.user = user

        if 'profile_pic' in request.FILES:
            profile.profile_pic = request.FILES['profile_pic']

        profile.save()
        registered = True

    else:
        print(user_form.errors, profile_form.errors)

else:
    user_form = UserForm()
    profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm()

return render(request, 'basic_app/registration.html',
              {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form, 'registered': registered})
```

Comment: You're calling `is_valid` on the class, not on the object. Replace `UserProfileInfoForm.is_valid()` by `profile_form.is_valid()`.

Answer (score 0):

You forget to take the **instance** of class. But, you used class. So, do this:

```
if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
```